# Flickering Text issue in Firefox in bootstrap carousel

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have used the bootstrap carousel for sliding the site content.

Dummy HTML for content carousel slider is as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h3>Content Title 1</h3>
      <span>Content Body Text 1</span>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <h3>Content Title 2</h3>
      <span>Content Body Text 2</span>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <h3>Content Title 3</h3>
      <span>Content Body Text 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If I run the website in the Firefox then the content of the carousel slightly flickers when sliding of a carousel-item is completed. This issue does not occur in Chrome.

I have tried the following solutions:

```
1..carousel-inner > .item {
        position: relative !important;
        -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease !important;
        -moz-transition: 0.3s ease !important;
        -o-transition: 0.3s ease !important;
        transition: 0.3s ease !important;
   }

2..carousel-inner {
        overflow: hidden !important;
        text-shadow: 0 0 !important;
   }
```

I checked other posts and maximum post suggest to overwrite the transition effect of the bootstrap carousel, which I tried in the first solution, but it's not working for me.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Do you have any specific reason to define custom item class and not use bootstrap4 carousel-item class which seems to work fine on Firefox for your example?

Comment: I have used to "carousel-item" class in my actual site, i have used item class for the dummy HTML which i have created in w3schools website. I am updating the question with this change.